# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT Error But Can't Find The Origin of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having this HTTP Headers error. I have been smashing my head over the wall for the past 3 days. Hope that didn't sound like I wanted to kill myself but still. Here's the error log, it has something to do with async/await I guess but I can't find where

```js
(node:17632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ...\src\api\Post.API.js:142:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:17632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17632) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the 
Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have been doing lots of research but no luck. I tried `return res.json(...)` and everything else that could possibly help, but again no luck there.

Server: Express.js
Version: Latest

Other Dependencies
Versions: Latest

Here's my code. I hope that you'll find and help me solve this issue and explain why it happened.

```js
// Fetch posts and their data
router.get("/fetch", async (req, res) => {
  let currentAccount = await AccountSchema.findOne({
    email: req.cookies.email,
    password: req.cookies.password
  });

  // Query methods
  let { accountId, postId, heart, getHearts } = req.query;

  // For checking if the post has any data or is empty
  function CheckPostLength(post) {
    if (post.hearts.usersHearted.length === 0) return false;
    else {
      _.each(post.hearts.usersHearted, (user) => {
        if (user.accountId == currentAccount._id) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // Getting the posts from the specified account ID
  if (accountId) {
    let account = await AccountSchema.findById(accountId);
    let posts = account.posts;

    _.each(posts, async (post) => {
      post.datefield = format(fromUnixTime((await post.datefield) / 1000), "MMM d/y h:mm b");
    });

    res.json(posts);
  }

  // Update the hearts of the post
  if (postId && heart) {
    // Author document of the post
    let postAuthor = await AccountSchema.findOne({ "posts._id": postId });
    // The post
    let post = postAuthor.posts.id(postId);
    // Checking if current account hearted the post
    let currentAccountHeartedThePost = CheckPostLength(post);

    // If current account liked the post
    if (currentAccountHeartedThePost) {
      // for (var v = 0; v < post.hearts.usersHearted.length; v++) {
      _.each(post.hearts.usersHearted, async (user) => {
        if (user.accountId == currentAccount.id) {
          res.json({ info: "UNHEARTED", data: post.hearts });
          post.hearts.numberOfHearts--;
          await post.hearts.usersHearted.pull(self);
          await postAuthor.save();
        }
      });
    }
    // If didn't
    else {
      post.hearts.numberOfHearts++;
      post.hearts.usersHearted.push({ accountId: currentAccount._id });
      res.json({ info: "HEARTED", data: post.hearts });
      await postAuthor.save();
    }
  }
  // Getting the hearts from the post
  if (postId && getHearts) {
    let postAuthor = await AccountSchema.findOne({ "posts._id": postId });
    let post = postAuthor.posts.id(postId);
    let hasCurrentAccount;

    _.each(post.hearts.usersHearted, (user) => {
      if (user.accountId == currentAccount.id) {
        hasCurrentAccount = true;
      } else {
        hasCurrentAccount = false;
      }
    });

    if (hasCurrentAccount === true) {
      res.json({ info: "ALREADY_HEARTED", data: post.hearts });
    } else {
      res.json({ info: "OK", data: post.hearts });
    }
  } else {
    let posts = [];
    let datefieldUpdate = (datefield) => {
      return format(fromUnixTime(datefield / 1000), "MMM d/y h:mm b");
    };
    let otherAccounts = await AccountSchema.find({ isPrivate: false })
      .where("_id")
      .ne(currentAccount.id);

    _.each(otherAccounts, (account) => {
      _.each(account.posts, (post) => {
        post.datefield = datefieldUpdate(post.datefield);
        posts.push(post);
      });
    });

    _.each(currentAccount.posts, (post) => {
      post.datefield = datefieldUpdate(post.datefield);
      posts.push(post);
    });

    _.sortBy(posts, ["datefield"]);

    res.json(posts);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you point out from which method you are getting this issue, which API call?

Comment: Yes, sure, thanks for having a look at it! From `router.get("/fetch"....)` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block for each and every `usersHearted` you are trying to send a response back, you only need to return `res.json` once when the process is done, This might be one of the places where you are getting the issue.

```
_.each(post.hearts.usersHearted, async (user) => {
    if (user.accountId == currentAccount.id) {
        post.hearts.numberOfHearts--;
        await post.hearts.usersHearted.pull(self);
        await postAuthor.save();
        return res.json({ info: "UNHEARTED", data: post.hearts });
    }
});
```

you can do this:

```
const responseData = []
_.each(post.hearts.usersHearted, async (user) => {
    if (user.accountId == currentAccount.id) {
        post.hearts.numberOfHearts--;
        await post.hearts.usersHearted.pull(self);
        await postAuthor.save();
        responseData.push(post.hearts)
    }
});
return res.json({ info: "UNHEARTED", data: responseData });
```

There are other instances where after returning a response you are trying to update data to DB, that is one thing you can do firsthand then return a result like below.

```
// If didn't
else {
    post.hearts.numberOfHearts++;
    post.hearts.usersHearted.push({ accountId: currentAccount._id });
    await postAuthor.save();
    return res.json({ info: "HEARTED", data: post.hearts });
}
```

And at this place you missed return in front of it, I added,

```
// Getting the posts from the specified account ID
if (accountId) {
    let account = {};
    let posts = account.posts;

    _.each(posts, async (post) => {
        post.datefield = format(fromUnixTime((await post.datefield) / 1000), "MMM d/y h:mm b");
    });

    return res.json(posts);
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to resolve your logic in the forEach loop and return a response once everything is done, and then you can test and update the rest.

Comment: Ohh, wow. Couldn't imagine I have missed that one detail. Thanks mate! You really helped me:) Take care! Also thanks for adding the missing return :)